# Writing Python Dataframe to MSSQL Table

Tags: python, sql-server, connection

I currently have a Python dataframe that is 23 columns and 20,000 rows.

Using Python code, I want to write my data frame into a MSSQL server that I have the credentials for.

As a test I am able to successfully write some values into the table using the code below:

```
connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};' 
                              'Server=XXX;' 
                              'Database=XXX;' 
                              'uid=XXX;' 
                              'pwd=XXX')

cursor = connection.cursor()

for index, row in df_EVENT5_15.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO MODREPORT(rowid, OPCODE, LOCATION, TRACKNAME)

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO MODREPORT(rowid, location) VALUES (?,?)", (5, 'test'))
connection.commit()
```

But how do I write all the rows in my data frame table to the MSSQL server?  In order to do so, I need to code up the following steps in my Python environment:

> 1. Delete all the rows in the MSSQL server table
> 2. Write my dataframe to the server

Answer (score 0):

When you say Python data frame, I'm assuming you're using a Pandas dataframe. If it's the case, then you could use the [`to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) function.

```
df.to_sql("MODREPORT", connection, if_exists="replace")
```

The `if_exists` argument set to *replace* will delete all the rows in the existing table before writing the records.

Comment: if_exists set to replace is not recommended because it will drop the table and recreate with possibly different DDL.

Answer (score 0):

I realise it's been a while since you asked but the easiest way to delete ALL the rows in the SQL server table (point 1 of the question) would be to send the command

```
TRUNCATE TABLE Tablename
```

This will drop all the data in the table but leave the table and indexes empty so you or the DBA would not need to recreate it. It also uses less of the transaction log when it runs.