# How to replace existing SQL database table columns with python data frame columns

Tags: python, sql

I want to replace database table values with dataframe values.
Need your advice !

I have a database with table `Data` as follows:

```
Ref    Text   Queue  EmailID    
1      ABC    PQ     abc@gmail.com
```

and a dataframe : `df['EmailID','Queue']` as follows:

```
 Queue  EmailID    
 GQ     abc@gmail.com
```

I want to replace EmailID, Queue from Data table with dataframe values in python.

I have a code as follows:

`cur.execute ("""UPDATE tblops.uploadmanagement SET Queue=%s WHERE EmailID=%s""", (df['Journey1'], df['EmailID']))`

I am getting following errors:

> The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 2 parameters were supplied',
>   'HY000'

Expected :

```
Ref    Text   Queue  EmailID    
1      ABC    GQ     abc@gmail.com
```

I have gone through following links:

[Writing Python Dataframe to MSSQL Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152944/writing-python-dataframe-to-mssql-table)

[pandas to sql seriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36487153/pandas-to-sql-seriver?rq=1)

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/python-mysql-insert/

Need your advice !

Comment: I have attempted editing for links and table/dataframe but could not apply it.

Comment: It needs to be `'%s'` not `%s` for the parameter markers. I'm not sure it will work, though, supplying whole Series objects.

Comment: In addition, adding numpy integers to an SQLite database results in BLOBs. I don't know if this will apply in MySQL.

Comment: @roganjosh for '%s' it gives error - Error converting data type varchar to bigint

Comment: I did say that I didn't think it would work. But now you actually have a query string that allows you to insert parameters, which was your first issue.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel E for edits:)

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/python-mysql-update/, try to do it in more step like in the link.
Step 1. Write the string query 
Step 2. Variable of param ( data = (df['Journey1'],df['EmailID'])
Step3. Execute the query ( cur..execute(query, data))

Comment: I attempted your suggetion @Daniel E but it didn't seem to work.It gives error:('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 2 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Comment: 1. query = "UPDATE ops.uploadmanagement SET Journey = %s WHERE EmailID = %s"                                                                                                              2. data = (df['Journey1'], df['EmailID'])                                                               3. cur.execute(query, data)